# Group nodes and remove duplicates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>8955444</itemId>
        <json:number name="Price">17.99</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">8955444</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
        <json:number name="freeShipFlag">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="Cartavailable">0</json:number>
        <json:number name="OnlineOnly">0</json:number>
        <json:number name="salePrice">9.39</json:number>
        <json:string name="onlinePurchDate">20150624</json:string>
        <json:string name="itemName">Conditioner</json:string>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>5646554</itemId>
        <json:number name="itemstock">179</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.49 LBS</json:string>
        <json:number name="Price">3.39</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">5646554</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">5646554892521</json:number>
        <json:string name="onlinePurchDate">20150624</json:string>
        <json:string name="itemName">oil</json:string>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>8955444</itemId>
        <json:number name="itemstock">419</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.79 LBS</json:string>
        <json:string name="unitSalePrice">NA</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineqty">0</json:number>
        <json:string name="size">6oz</json:string>
        <json:string name="category">beauty</json:string>
        <json:string name="itemId">8955444</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineStock">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="shipsaveFlag">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="onsale">0</json:number>
        <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>905678911</itemId>
        <json:number name="itemstock">157</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.23 LBS</json:string>
        <json:string name="unitSalePrice">NA</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineqty">0</json:number>
        <json:string name="title">Cleanser</json:string>
        <json:number name="Price">6.49</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">908911</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">88941105671610</json:number>
        <json:number name="freeShipFlag">1</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>8955444</itemId>
        <json:string name="itemId">8955444</json:string>
        <json:string name="storePurchDate">20150115</json:string>
        <json:number name="storePurchqty">1</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>1410743567</itemId>
        <json:string name="itemId">1410743567</json:string>
        <json:string name="storePurchDate">20141226</json:string>
        <json:number name="storePurchqty">8</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
</json:object>
```

I have this xml and i need to group it to output based on itemId. Once we group the two nodes there might be duplicates, which we need to remove. how to write this in muenchian method.

Tried the following but it is not changing anything

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" extension-element-prefixes="xsi" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi json">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="items-by-id" match="itemConfig" use="itemId"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="json:object[@name = 'items']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="itemConfig[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items-by-id', itemId)[1])]" mode="group"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="itemConfig" mode="group">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="itemId"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('items-by-id', itemId)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>8955444</itemId>
        <json:number name="Price">17.99</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">8955444</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
        <json:number name="freeShipFlag">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="Cartavailable">0</json:number>
        <json:number name="OnlineOnly">0</json:number>
        <json:number name="salePrice">9.39</json:number>
        <json:string name="onlinePurchDate">20150624</json:string>
        <json:string name="itemName">Conditioner</json:string>
        <json:number name="itemstock">419</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.79 LBS</json:string>
        <json:string name="unitSalePrice">NA</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineqty">0</json:number>
        <json:string name="size">6oz</json:string>
        <json:string name="category">beauty</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineStock">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="shipsaveFlag">1</json:number>
        <json:number name="onsale">0</json:number>
        <json:string name="storePurchDate">20150115</json:string>
        <json:number name="storePurchqty">1</json:number>             
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>5646554</itemId>
        <json:number name="itemstock">179</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.49 LBS</json:string>
        <json:number name="Price">3.39</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">5646554</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">5646554892521</json:number>
        <json:string name="onlinePurchDate">20150624</json:string>
        <json:string name="itemName">oil</json:string>
        <json:string name="storePurchDate">20141226</json:string>
        <json:number name="storePurchqty">8</json:number>        
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>905678911</itemId>
        <json:number name="itemstock">157</json:number>
        <json:string name="wt">0.23 LBS</json:string>
        <json:string name="unitSalePrice">NA</json:string>
        <json:number name="onlineqty">0</json:number>
        <json:string name="title">Cleanser</json:string>
        <json:number name="Price">6.49</json:number>
        <json:string name="itemId">908911</json:string>
        <json:number name="upcNum">88941105671610</json:number>
        <json:number name="freeShipFlag">1</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>
<json:object name="items">
    <itemConfig>
        <itemId>1410743567</itemId>
        <json:string name="itemId">1410743567</json:string>
        <json:string name="storePurchDate">20141226</json:string>
        <json:number name="storePurchqty">8</json:number>
    </itemConfig>
</json:object>    
</json:object>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please cut short the input(after making it a valid XML as there is no namespace declared for `json` prefix) to be enough to describe the problem, and post the expected output.

Comment: updated. Removed most of the nodes. Just showed few cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once we group the two nodes there might be duplicates, which we need
>   to remove.

In order to group the `items` nodes **and** remove duplicates within each group, you must apply Muenchian grouping twice:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>  

<xsl:key name="items-by-id" match="itemConfig" use="itemId"/>
<xsl:key name="item-by-name" match="itemConfig/*" use="concat(../itemId, '|', @name)"/>

<xsl:template match="/json:object">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- for each group --> 
        <xsl:for-each select="json:object/itemConfig[count(. | key('items-by-id', itemId)[1]) = 1]">
            <json:object name="items">
                <itemConfig>
                    <!-- get distinct items in this group -->   
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('items-by-id', itemId)/*[count(. | key('item-by-name', concat(../itemId, '|', @name))[1]) = 1]"/>
                </itemConfig>
            </json:object>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test Input**

```
 <json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
    <json:object name="items">
        <itemConfig>
            <itemId>123</itemId>
            <json:number name="Price">17.99</json:number>
            <json:string name="itemId">123</json:string>
            <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
            <json:number name="salePrice">9.39</json:number>
        </itemConfig>
    </json:object>
    <json:object name="items">
        <itemConfig>
            <itemId>456</itemId>
            <json:number name="Price">3.39</json:number>
            <json:number name="upcNum">456892521</json:number>
            <json:string name="itemName">oil</json:string>
        </itemConfig>
    </json:object>
    <json:object name="items">
        <itemConfig>
            <itemId>123</itemId>
            <json:string name="itemId">123</json:string>
            <json:number name="onlineStock">1</json:number>
            <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
        </itemConfig>
    </json:object>
    <json:object name="items">
        <itemConfig>
            <itemId>456</itemId>
            <json:number name="upcNum">456892521</json:number>
            <json:string name="category">beauty</json:string>
        </itemConfig>
    </json:object>
    <json:object name="items">
        <itemConfig>
            <itemId>123</itemId>
            <json:string name="itemId">123</json:string>
            <json:string name="storePurchDate">20150115</json:string>
        </itemConfig>
    </json:object>
</json:object>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<json:object xmlns:json="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/2009/jsonx">
   <json:object name="items">
      <itemConfig>
         <itemId>123</itemId>
         <json:number name="Price">17.99</json:number>
         <json:string name="itemId">123</json:string>
         <json:number name="upcNum">54654654546</json:number>
         <json:number name="salePrice">9.39</json:number>
         <json:number name="onlineStock">1</json:number>
         <json:string name="storePurchDate">20150115</json:string>
      </itemConfig>
   </json:object>
   <json:object name="items">
      <itemConfig>
         <itemId>456</itemId>
         <json:number name="Price">3.39</json:number>
         <json:number name="upcNum">456892521</json:number>
         <json:string name="itemName">oil</json:string>
         <json:string name="category">beauty</json:string>
      </itemConfig>
   </json:object>
</json:object>
```

Note that this assumes that `<itemId>` is the only one in its group without a `name` attribute.